# How to make Toolbar hide/show smooth on listview scroll. android

Tags: android, listview

I am using this code for show/hide toolbar on listview down/up scroll.

```
brandListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (view.getId() == brandListView.getId()) {
            final int currentFirstVisibleItem = brandListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
            } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                // getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
            }

            mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
        }
    }
});
```

Although it is hiding/showing listview as expected, but transition is not at all smooth. Its kind of very sudden flicking kind of effect.

Can any one help me how can i make it smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Try my library: [RetractableToolbar](https://github.com/michelelacorte/RetractableToolbar)

You have to import in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'it.michelelacorte.retractabletoolbar:library:1.0.0'
```

Than in your Activity class:

```
RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener showHideToolbarListener;
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(showHideToolbarListener = new RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener(toolbar));

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            showHideToolbarListener.onRestoreInstanceState((RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.State) savedInstanceState
                    .getParcelable(RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.SHOW_HIDE_TOOLBAR_LISTENER_STATE));
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is only for `RecyclerView`, but I noticed that you need a `ListView` then you should take a look at this file: [RetractableToolbarUtil](https://github.com/michelelacorte/RetractableToolbar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/it/michelelacorte/retractabletoolbar/RetractableToolbarUtil.java), 
modify it to fit your needs!